# Azure Stream Analytics - How to use ST_WITHIN method by joining reference blob data contains polygon details with lat & long from Input data

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How to use ST_WITHIN method by joining reference blob data contains polygon details with lat & long from Input data. i am facing problem with JOIN method

Answer (score 1):

It is not yet possible within the ASA to place one method within the other .
In your case, use the with option to segment the search.

```
Ex:

with cteCreatePoint(
SELECT 
   e.PartitionByDeviceId,
   e.deviceid,
   e.UnixTime,
   e.MessageParsedTimestamp,
   e.Latitude,
   e.Longitude,
   e.ObdVIN,
   e.Address,
   createpoint(e.latitude,e.longitude) as point,
   as Inbound  
   FROM geoinput as e
)
```

In the sequence with the return make the crossing to obtain the return within the function

ex:

```
select
a.*,
b.*
into [exit]
from [cteCreatePoint] a
JOIN [georef] on ST_WITHIN(a.point,b.geometry) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT 
   e.PartitionByDeviceId,
   e.deviceid,
   e.UnixTime,
   e.MessageParsedTimestamp,
   e.Latitude,
   e.Longitude,
   e.ObdVIN,
   e.Address,
   ST_WITHIN(createpoint(e.latitude,e.longitude), arrayElement.ArrayValue.geometry) 
   as Inbound  
   FROM geoinput as e
   CROSS JOIN georef as event
   CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.features) AS  arrayElement
```